# Proper technique for prompting users to reconfirm login details

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to hide sensitive information on my site by prompting users to reconfirm their login details before allowing them to see it.

I have two python functions: `

```
@settings.route('/api_login_check/', methods=['GET'])
@access_level('setting_admin')
def api_login_check():
    return login(api_verifying = True)

@settings.route('/api_information/<int:verified>', methods=['GET'])
@settings.route('/api_information/', methods=['GET'])
@access_level('setting_admin')
def api_information(verified = 0):
    if verified:
        return render_template('api_information.html', v = True)
    else:
        return render_template('api_information.html', v = False)`
```

Basically how it's working at the moment is on the page where you would originally navigate to this information, it calls api_information, and verified defaults to False. Then it renders the template of the page regardless but with Jinja I hide all the content and redirect them to api_login_check. From there it prompts the user to login and will finally call api_information again on login success.

The issue here is that it doesn't really redirect very well back to the api_information function. At this current state the code works, but the URL will still show api_login_check.

```
if (successful==true) {
    {% if api_verifying %}
        var verified = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{url_for('settings.api_information', verified = 1)}}",
            type: "GET",
            data: verified,
            success:function(response){ document.write(response); }  
            });
    {% endif %}
```

My two real questions are these:
Is there a way to properly use JS to send a variable back through to Python without ajax, and if there isn't, how do you get ajax to properly display the api_information URL?

Is the fundamental technique I'm using to go about doing this is really far away from more commonplace methods? If so I'd love some pointers or tips!


Thanks everyone in advnace.

Comment: If this is just about what URL is displayed, take a look at the documentation forJavascript's history.pushState()

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to me because, if I understand it correctly, the user only has to add a 1 to the api_information url, to be shown all information. So he doesn't need to verify at all. If a user is verified you should store this in the session (server-side); this is not something you want to leave to client-side code to control.